# Change the css attributes of a div in a parent window from an iframe

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, parent

Is there any way to use jquery in an iframe to change the stylesheet that's being used in the parent?

I don't have access to the parent headers and can't change the css manually there, I can add java or jquery code to the iframe which both reside on the same domain.
I'm hoping I can use the iframe and jquery to make the customizations that I want to the parent's css by simply forcing the parent to load another stylesheet.

The newly linked stylesheet would have to reside on a different domain.
Thanks.

Comment: @MathewMacLean, when making tag wiki edits, please **do not** simply copy and paste stuff from wikipedia or a vendor's web site... especially without attribution.  Also, please be careful to create wikis for tags that are actually legitimate and not blatant typos, like the one you created for [tag:webshphere].  The tag should have been removed from the one question that had it, not given a wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on the same domain you shouldn't have an issue with XSS. You need to first target the top most document object. Then append the stylesheet to the parent's head. Try this:

```
var link = '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/file.css" />';

$(window.top.document).find('head').append(link);
```

You would then place your styles in the CSS document you are appending.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply!
I tried that and it's not working for me yet, but I may be doing it wrong. 

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
var link = '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.domain.com/globalcss/globalcontent.css" />';
$(window.top).find('head').append(link);
}
</script>

Comment: I updated the answer. You need to add document to the `window.top` string.